# Are connection forms tensorial objets?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

I think the standard answer is they are not, for example, from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form). Under a coordinate transformation of $e' =eA$ where $e$ is a set of frames and $A$ the transformation matrix, connection form $\omega$ transform as
$$\omega'=A^{-1}\omega A + A^{-1}\mathrm{d}A$$
Apperatently apart from the usual tensoril transformation term $A^{-1}\omega A$, there is an additional $A^{-1}\mathrm{d}A$ term.

However, due to the $\mathcal{F}$-linear w.r.t. $W$ as in $\nabla_W V$, one can consider $\nabla_{(\cdot)}V$ with a fixed vector field $V$ a $(1, 1)$ tensor field (reference: pg. 204 of [1]).

Aren't connection forms the same construction as $\nabla_{(\cdot)}V$? i.e.
$$\nabla_Ve_a = \omega^b_a(V)e_b$$
This is just picking a set of frame fields $e_a$ in place of $V$ in $\nabla_{(\cdot)} V$, and we decompose the result on to the same set of frames?

How do I reconcile these two understandings?

[1]: Schutz, Bernard - Geometrical methods of mathematical physics. Cambridge university press 1980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that $U$ is the domain of the frame $e$. In parts:

- Each $\omega^a_{~b}$ is a $1$-form on $U$ precisely due to $\mathcal{F}$-linearity of the connection $\nabla$ in the lower argument, yes.
- The whole matrix $(\omega^a_{~b})_{a,b=1}^n$ is a $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb R)$-valued $1$-form on $U$.
- However, $(U,\{\omega^a_{~b} \mid a,b=1,\ldots,n\})$ are not the local components of any tensor on $M$, because whenever $(\widetilde{U} ,\{\widetilde{\omega}^a_{~b}\mid a,b=1,\ldots, n\})$ corresponds to a second frame $\widetilde{e}$ on $\widetilde{U}$ (with $\widetilde{e} = eA$ on $U\cap\widetilde{U}\neq\varnothing$), they do not satisfy the tensor transformation law (due to $A^{-1}{\rm d}A$).

Comment: So with a fixed $a$, the "column" $\omega^b_a$ are the components of a 1-form hence a tensorial object. However, the entire matrix $\omega$ is not tensorial?

Comment: Right, because $\nabla_W V$ is not tensorial in $V$, only in $W$.